# Laravel response status code set to 400 but browser reports 200

Tags: backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4, http-headers, http-status-codes

I'm trying to return a 400 status code from Laravel. I've setup a simple test in my controller:

```
return Response::json(["Test", "Array"], 400);
```

And look at web inspector I get a 200 OK.

If I dump the response:

```
object(Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)#306 (8) {
  ["data":protected]=>
  string(16) "["Test","Array"]"
  ["callback":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["headers"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag)#315 (5) {
   ["computedCacheControl":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["no-cache"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["cookies":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["headerNames":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cache-control"]=>
      string(13) "Cache-Control"
      ["date"]=>
      string(4) "Date"
      ["content-type"]=>
      string(12) "Content-Type"
    }
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cache-control"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "no-cache"
      }
      ["date"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(29) "Wed, 02 Apr 2014 20:03:14 GMT"
      }
      ["content-type"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "application/json"
      }
    }
    ["cacheControl":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["content":protected]=>
  string(16) "["Test","Array"]"
  ["version":protected]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["statusCode":protected]=>
  int(400)
  ["statusText":protected]=>
  string(11) "Bad Request"
  ["charset":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

I can see that the status code is set to 400 and the statusText is Bad Request.

Basically I'm using Backbone.js in conjunction with Laravel and need to return a status code other than 200 to catch errors on save.

This seems like such a simple thing to do, does anyone know what I'm having this issue?

**UPDATE**

After some head bashing I've found a (not very ideal) work around to achieve what I need, and logged a issue on the Laravel GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2796

Basically I took my controller out of the equation and tried this as a route:

```
Route::get('/bad-request', function() {
    $response['state'] = "error";
    $response['errors'] = ["name" => ["A product name is required"]];

    return Response::json($response, 400);
});
```

Same issue, returns a 200. Found this work around for the time being:

```
Route::get('/bad-request', function() {
    $response['state'] = "error";
    $response['errors'] = ["name" => ["A product name is required"]];

    http_response_code(400);
    return Response::json($response, 400);
});
```

I'd much rather do this with Laravel than forcing it with PHP. Also I've tried `Response::make` and that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I don't believe the Json response is handled the same way by the web layer as it would be by, say, an API call.  If you want to return a 404 to the web layer, you'll have to use something like `return Response::error(404)`.

However, I'm confused by why that would matter - as long as you're getting the correct response from the tool you're using to make the request, why does the web layer need to see a 404?

Comment: @RyanHavoc i don't see why you'd get a 200 response in your web inspector. i just tested it myself and also get a 400. even your dump returns 400. there muste be more in the bush we're not seeing.

Comment: This should work. Could you share your full controller?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself recently, it should work but for some reason it doesn't. You need to make the response object yourself.

```
Response::make(["Test", "Array"], 400);
```

This will still return the array as JSON automatically for some reason...

Comment: It works perfect as API, but when called from tests, it again gives 200.. any idea why

Comment: a look in the [API](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_make) tells me that make expect a string while json expects an array. both didn't work for me my __statuscode__ is still __200__.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
new Response(Array,400); //will return 400
```

although the api will tell you otherwise, this is not working:

```
new Response()->json(Array,400); // will return 200
new Response()->make(Array,400); // will return 200
```